# Why are my CoreData updates not persisting when I relaunch the app?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to edit a value in a previously saved object in CoreData.

**The object appears to have been updated, *until* I relaunch the app, and the value is now set to 'nil'.**

Here is my method for saving the changes:

```
class SaveNewQuickShareTrip: NSManagedObject {

    static func addNewTrip(_ username: String, newTrip: TripModel, tripType : String, in context: NSManagedObjectContext) {

        let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: Constants.User)
        request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "username=%@", username)
        request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false

        var currentTrips : [TripModel] = Array<TripModel>()

        do {
            let matches = try context.fetch(request)

            if matches.count == 1 {
                for userData in matches as! [NSManagedObject] {
                    currentTrips = userData.value(forKey: tripType) as! Array<TripModel>
                    print("currentTrips OLD count = ", currentTrips.count)
                    currentTrips.append(newTrip)
                    userData.setValue(currentTrips, forKey: Constants.quickShareTrips)
                    print("currentTrips NEW count = ", currentTrips.count)
                }
                do {
                    try context.save()
                } catch {
                    print("Saving the new trip failed!")
                }
            }
        } catch {
            print("Something went wrong when saving the quick share trip.")
        }
    }
}
```

And code I'm using to retrieve the object upon launch:

```
class UserRetrieval: NSManagedObject {

    static func fetchUser(_ username: String, in context: NSManagedObjectContext) -> [NSManagedObject] {

        let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: Constants.User)
        request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "username=%@", username)
        request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false

        var theUser = [NSManagedObject]()

        do {
            let matches = try context.fetch(request)

            if let records = matches as? [NSManagedObject] {
                theUser = records
            }
        } catch {
            print("Can't find User.")
        }

        return theUser
    }
}
```

Comment: You code check out ok. Maybe on launch you're fetching another object. Share that code with us. Lets have a look

Comment: @staticVoidMan - cheers! ^Question updated with code I'm using to fetch the object.

Comment: Hm... looking like trouble. Can you share the code where you get `nil`. I am guessing something but want to be sure.

Comment: The code where I get 'nil' is in the original 'addNewTrip' method posted above. When I relaunch the app, I try adding another trip, and when I try and retrieve the current value of the Array, it is nil.

Comment: does your code step through properly, i.e. does the following `print("currentTrips NEW count = ", currentTrips.count)` log as expected?

Comment: and what's the difference between `tripType` & `Constants.quickShareTrips`? as both are used to access/modify `currentTrips`